# React - Display all properties of an object

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm sure, this is a simple question, but actually I cannot find where my mistake is.
I have a component where an object has not a fixed number of properties. 
Actually I'm having trouble to display all properties of the object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FreightRelayWithPricesAndAreas extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          freightRelayPrice: props.freightRelayPrice
        };
    }

    render() {
      const Fragment = React.Fragment;
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <tr>
            {
              Object.keys(this.state.freightRelayPrice).map(function(key) {
                  return <td className="whiteSpaceNoWrap">{ this.state.freightRelayPrice[key] }</td>
              })
            }
          </tr>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
}

export default FreightRelayWithPricesAndAreas
```

The error is always:

> app.js:57763 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of
>   undefined
>
> at app.js:57763
>
> at Array.map ()
>
> at FreightRelayWithPricesAndAreas.render (app.js:57759)
>
> at finishClassComponent (app.js:48488)
>
> at updateClassComponent (app.js:48465)
>
> at beginWork (app.js:48840)
>
> at performUnitOfWork (app.js:50839)
>
> at workLoop (app.js:50903)
>
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:41157)
>
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (app.js:41196)

As I already said, I'm sure this is simple, but actually I don't see the reason why this happens. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: this.state = {
          freightRelayPrice: this.props.freightRelayPrice
        };

Comment: the are tens of duplicate to this question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Object.keys(this.state.freightRelayPrice).map(function(key) {
   return <td className="whiteSpaceNoWrap">{ this.state.freightRelayPrice[key] }</td>
})
```

Inside callback function `this` is a function context itself. You can use arrow function

```
Object.keys(this.state.freightRelayPrice).map((key) => {
   return <td className="whiteSpaceNoWrap">{ this.state.freightRelayPrice[key] }</td>
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation. That's it!